# Java Spring Method with @Cachable not intercepted by AOP Proxy

Tags: java, spring, factory, spring-aop

*Situation -*

During the implementation of an Activity tracking system, to improve performance I resort to Caching some repeated DB calls using @Cachable annotation.

The structure looks like this:

An Interface

- `ActivityCaseService<T>`

An Abstract

- `AbstractActivityCaseImpl<T> implements ActivityCaseService<T>`

Concrete classes

- `LoginActivityCaseImpl extends AbstractActivityCaseImpl<LoginActivityCase>`
- `CallActivityCaseImpl extends AbstractActivityCaseImpl<CallActivityCase>`

Based on the type of `ActivityCaseType` requested, it switches between LoginActivity or CallActivity implementation and executes the methods on them. Have implemented *ActivityCaseServiceFactory* to get the instance of a class at runtime.

But, during the implementation, @Cachable added on the method gets ignored. I have an intuition that beans returned by *ActivityCaseServiceFactory* are not Cacheable weaved proxies, that's why annotation is not working, but don't understand the exact issue, and how to rectify if that's the problem!

Reference:

- spring.version 4.3.9.RELEASE
- @Cachable works perfectly for other services in the same codebase

`ActivityCaseServiceFactory`

```
@Service
public class ActivityCaseServiceFactory {
      
      /*ActivityCaseType:Enum*/
      private Map<ActivityCaseType, ActivityCaseService<?>> activityCaseTypeVsActivityCaseService = new HashMap<>();

      public ActivityCaseServiceFactory(List<ActivityCaseService<?>> abstractActivityCaseServiceImpls) {
            activityCaseTypeVsActivityCaseService =
                    abstractActivityCaseServiceImpls.stream()
                            .collect(Collectors.toMap(ActivityCaseService::getActivityCaseType, A -> A));
      }

      public ActivityCaseService<?> getService(ActivityCaseType activityCaseType) {
            return activityCaseTypeVsActivityCaseService.get(activityCaseType);
      }
}
```

`ActivityCaseService`

```
public interface ActivityCaseService<T> extends BeanInitializer {

      ActivityCaseType getActivityCaseType();

      /* Method executed based on ActivityCaseType */
      List<? extends ActivityBaseCaseDto> getActivityByUserIds(
              ActivityInRangeQuery activityInRangeQuery, List<Integer> userIds, Boolean fromCache);

      /* Tried to declare here so that execution could be intercepted by AOP Proxy */
      Optional<List<T>> findActivityInRangeQuery(
              ActivityInRangeQuery activityInRangeQuery, List<Integer> agentIds, Boolean fromCache);

}
```

`AbstractActivityCaseServiceImpl`

```
public abstract class AbstractActivityCaseServiceImpl<T extends ActivityCase> implements ActivityCaseService<T> {

      public abstract ActivityCaseType getActivityCaseType();

      public abstract List<? extends ActivityBaseCaseDto> getActivityByUserIds(
              ActivityInRangeQuery activityInRangeQuery,
              List<Integer> userIds,
              Boolean fromCache);

      public abstract Optional<List<T>> findActivityInRangeQuery(
              ActivityInRangeQuery activityInRangeQuery, List<Integer> agentIds, Boolean fromCache);


}
```

`LoginActivityCaseImpl`

```
@Service(value = "LoginActivityService")
public class LoginAbstractActivityCaseServiceImpl extends AbstractActivityCaseServiceImpl<LoginActivityCase> {

      @Override
      public ActivityCaseType getActivityCaseType() {
            return ActivityCaseType.LOGIN;
      }

      @Override
      public List<LoginActivityBaseCaseDto> getActivityByUserIds(
              ActivityInRangeQuery activityInRangeQuery, List<Integer> userIds, Boolean fromCache) {
                  String[]
                          beanNamesForType =
                          applicationContext.getBeanNamesForType(ResolvableType.forClassWithGenerics(ActivityCaseService.class,
                                  LoginActivityCase.class));

                  (List<LoginActivityCase>) applicationContext.getBean(beanNamesForType[0],
                          ActivityCaseService.class).findActivityInRangeQuery(activityInRangeQuery, agents, fromCache);

                  /*- More logic to transform List<LoginActivityCase> received above -*/
      }

      /* ----> @Cacheable not working here <---- */
      @Override
      @Cacheable(value = CacheNames.ACTIVITY_CACHE,
                 condition = "#fromCache",
                 unless = "#result == null")
      public Optional<List<LoginActivityCase>> findActivityInRangeQuery(
              ActivityInRangeQuery activityInRangeQuery, List<Integer> agentIds, Boolean fromCache) {

            /* -- Time taking IO calls -- */
            
      }

}
```

`OtherService`

```
      @Autowired
      private ActivityCaseServiceFactory activityCaseServiceFactory;

      public List<ActivityBaseCaseDto> getActivityForUserAndTeam(/*Params*/) {
            return activityCaseServiceFactory.getService(ActivityCaseType.LOGIN)
                    .getActivityByUserIds(ActivityInRangeQuery.builder().build(),new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2)),true);
      }
```

Have been scratching my head for 2 days while searching solution to resolve this issue, but all in vain :). So, before moving to Custom Cache implementation, thought to get help from this amazing StackOverflow community.

What am I doing wrong with @Cachable? And also, open to any criticism/suggestion about how the code is overall structured to implement Activity Tracking.

Adding some screenshots to give more context:

[image: Factory Bean Instance]
[image: LoginActivity Instance executing cachable annotated method]

Comment: Not sure but maybe it is because `@Cacheable` does not work when called inside same bean. So calling `getActivityByUserIds` inside `LoginAbstractActivityCaseServiceImpl` will not use cache for `findActivityInRangeQuery` but calls outside proxy would use the cache.

Comment: @pirho For the same reason, I tried invoking the @Cachable method from "outside" the class through `ActivityCaseService`, ideally it gets intercepted by proxy, but not happening in this case. :(

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you tried but `LoginAbstractActivityCaseServiceImpl` IS an `ActivityCaseService` so not other bean or outside proxy?

Comment: Your debugger screenshots are not really helping me, because there is too much context information missing. Especially the code in the first one looks weird (more than one statement). It would be better if I could see for myself, then the answer would probably be straightforward. I have ideas what might be the problem, but want to avoid speculating. So please condense your real application into a minimal version still reproducing the problem, i.e. an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Remove and rename whatever you like, but make sure it still reproduces the problem.

Comment: I think @pirho is right. In your other service, when calling findActivityInRangeQuery, it is still from getActivityByUserIds in the same bean.

Comment: Please be kind enough to provide some feedback to the people who are trying to help you. Saying nothing is simply not very polite.

Comment: Cachable was working, it was an issue regarding the connection establishment with the underlying data store(Redis, in this case).  Thanks for the help.